# How to create 3D objects in Java SE6

Tags: java, class, 3d, draw, bluej

I need someone tell me some info on how to create 3D java objects in Java SE6, I am not using it in a applet but in a regular java class,  here is where i am upto.  I am still learning java at colledge but, since I am a freshman and I am at winter break I though of why not study java more my self.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.math.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Java_PaintBrush extends Canvas
{
private static byte mode;
private static byte mode2;
private static byte mode3;
private static final byte ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD=7;
private static final byte ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD2=2;
private static final byte ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD3=4;
private static final byte ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD4=3;
private static final byte ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD5=5;
private static final String[] TYPES=
{
    "1D",
    "Circle",
    "Oval",
    "Round Rectangle",
    "Rectangle",
    "Irregular",
    "3D"
};
private static short[] image=new short[ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD2];
private static short[] pop_up_size=new short[ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD2];
private static short[] shape_size=new short[ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD2];
private static short[] shape_size_with_coord=new short[ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD3];
private static short[] shape_3D_size=new short[ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD4];
private static short[] shape_3D_size_with_coord=new short[ARRAY_SIZE_STANDARD5];
private static final String VERSION="V 0.01.000";
private static final String PROG_NAME="Java PaintBrush";
private static final String EXT=".javpb";
private static String file_name;
private static String full_file_name;
private static byte mode4;
private static final String[] TYPES_3D=
{
    ""
};
private static byte enter;
private static byte enter2;
private static byte enter3;
private static byte amberlite;
private byte amberiguous=amberlite;
private static byte proxyer;
private static byte napping;
private byte nap=napping;
//"colerse.txt"
private static final String[]   TYPES_1D=
{
    "Line"
};
public static void MyCanvas()throws IOException
{

}
public void Java_PaintBrush()throws IOException
{
    if(nap==1)
        converter();
    else
    {
        converter();
    }
}
public void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
    if(amberiguous==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        int a,b;
        a=(int)image[0];
        b=(int)image[1];
        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
        graphics.drawRect(0,0,a,b);

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
    Start_up();
    new_old();
    if(mode==1)
    {
        getPopup_size();
        proxyer=0;
        startPopup();
        getImage_size();
        amberlite=1;
        setAmberlite();
        Java_PaintBrush porter=new Java_PaintBrush();
        startPopup();

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
public static void Start_up()throws IOException
{

}
public static void new_old()throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    out.println("Enter 1 for, new Java_PaintBrush image.  Enter 2 for, ");
    out.print("open an existing Java PaintBrush image.  :  ");
    mode=keyboard.nextByte();
    byte a,b;
    a=1;
    b=2;
    while(mode<a||mode>b)
    {

    }
}
public static void startPopup()throws IOException
{
    if(proxyer==0)
    {
        short a,b;
        a=pop_up_size[0];
        b=pop_up_size[1];
        napping=1;
        // We initialize our class here
        Java_PaintBrush canvas = new Java_PaintBrush();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(a, b);
        amberlite=0;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Here we add it to the frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        napping=0;
    }
    else
    {
       short a,b;
       a=pop_up_size[0];
       b=pop_up_size[1];
       Java_PaintBrush canvas = new Java_PaintBrush();
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(a, b);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       // Here we add it to the frame
       frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
public static void getPopup_size()throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    byte loops;
    loops=0;
    out.print("Enter length of pop up.  :  ");
    pop_up_size[loops]=keyboard.nextShort();
    out.print("Enter the height of pop up.  :  ");
    loops++;
    pop_up_size[loops]=keyboard.nextShort();
}
public static void getImage_size()throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    byte loops;
    loops=0;
    out.print("Enter the length of the image.  :  ");
    image[loops]=keyboard.nextShort();
    while(image[loops]<=0||image[loops]>pop_up_size[loops])
    {

    }
    loops++;
    out.print("Enter the height of the image.  :  ");
    image[loops]=keyboard.nextShort();
    while(image[loops]<=0||image[loops]>pop_up_size[loops])
    {

    }
}
public static void setAmberlite()throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter outputFile=new PrintWriter("colerse.txt");
    outputFile.println(amberlite);
    outputFile.close();
}
public void converter()throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    String value;
    File myFile=new File("colerse.txt");
    Scanner inputFile=new Scanner(myFile);
    value=inputFile.nextLine();
    inputFile.close();
    amberiguous=Byte.parseByte(value);
    proxyer=1;
}
```

}

Comment: What part are you having problems with?

Comment: I found this book very good for 3D graphics: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0470031603/

Comment: What is the desired behavior of the code, and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: I'm trying to make something like paint except, to add shapes one has to type it into blue j terminal window.  I just needed to know how to draw or create 3d objects with java a simlar way in which 2D objects are drawn.

Comment: code is not fully complte. I thoght of asking the user to input which shape they want to insert ,but i thought 3D might be the hardest to code so I thought whynot start with 3D and end with !d shapes which is easy.

Comment: If you would like, I have a fully implemented paint program I made last fall with swing.